# Plasma can be sustained from many types of gases. Is this dictionally right?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In one of my textbooks, there is a line that reads 'Plasma can be ignited and **sustained from** many types of gases.'

Is this usage correct? I would have rephrased this sentence as 'Plasma can be ignited from and sustained by many types of gases' (which also sounds a little 'unusual'). I have seen the expression 'sustained from' used in association with accidents (as 'injuries sustained from...') .MWD defines 'sustain' as:

> Definition of sustain
>
> transitive verb
>
> 1 :  to give support or relief to
>
> 2 :  to supply with sustenance :  nourish
>
> 3 :  keep up, prolong
>
> 4 :  to support the weight of :  prop; also :  to carry or withstand (a >weight or pressure)
>
> 5 :  to buoy up sustained by hope
>
> 6a :  to bear up underb :  suffer, undergo sustained heavy losses
>
> 7a :  to support as true, legal, or justb :  to allow or admit as valid >the court sustained the motion
>
> 8 :  to support by adequate proof :  confirm testimony that sustains >our contention

What I want to know is if this usage( in this context) is valid and if it is, what does the author mean?

Comment: It is normally **sustained by** not **sustained from** when the meaning is "to be supported or nourished", with the object of preposition **by** being that which sustains.   **from** refers to a source or origin or cause, and that's why it's used in contexts like "injuries sustained from an accident".  If the plasmas are understood to be a product or result, then "from" is acceptable.

Comment: *Dictionally* is ambiguous at best, and otherwise  esoteric. See [One Look](https://www.onelook.com/?w=Dictionally&ls=a). In what sense are you using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I am not a native speaker, to my ear in this context (based on what I have read on the subject) the verb *sustain* implies rather some action or source of energy than source of matter and it is more synonymous to the verb *keep*.

From [here](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=QlPyAAAAMAAJ&q=%22sustain%20plasma%20with%22&dq=%22sustain%20plasma%20with%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx9azD9PHTAhUCUbwKHQSjCnwQ6AEIJzAB):

> [...] it was able to sustain plasma with a power as small as 1 W.

Or [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26931934):

> High frequency microwaves allowed to create and sustain plasma with significant density [...]

Perhaps the word *using* might do:

[here](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/photopolymer/26/4/26_555/_pdf):

> [...] we have developed a new device to produce a stable glow-like
>   plasma using helium gas.

The minimal change I would do in your sentence would be:

> Plasma can be ignited and sustained **using** many types of gases.